# Subclassing a user-defined exception in a user-defined class in Python

Tags: python, class, oop, object, subclass

Why does this work:

```
class A:
    class BError(Exception):
        pass
    class CError(AError):
        pass
```

But this doesn't:

```
class A:
    class BError(Exception):
        pass
    class CError(A.BError):
        pass
```

If "method 1" works for calling class variables, why doesn't it work for "class classes"

Comment: There is no `AError` in the first example.

Comment: Class objects are only created once their *entire class statement* has been executed.

Answer (score 0):

When compiling, python builds the class and then assigns it to a named variable in the enclosing namespace. In the first example (assuming you really meant `class CError(BError)`), `BError` has been compiled and assigned to the `A` class namespace so it is visible for the next class. But in the second example, the top class has not yet been assigned to the global `A` variable so `A.BError` cannot be found.

The problem can be demonstrated as:

```
>>> class A:
...     print('A' in globals())
... 
False
>>> print('A' in globals())
True
>>>
```